# Is there a way to export all the Visual Studio Macro variables

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, configuration-files

Is there a way to export all the Visual Studio Macro Variables? I need to compare what macro variable affect after common configuration file (*.props) changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Build your project with `/verbosity:diagnostic`.  The resulting build log will include listings of all of the MSBuild Properties and Items at various points during the build.  You can enable diagnostic verbosity by...

- Changing the logging verbosity in the IDE.  Under *Tools* => *Options*, go to *Projects and Solutions* => *Build and Run* and change the *MSBuild project build log file verbosity* and change it to *Diagnostic*, or
- Build your project on the command line using `msbuild /verbosity:diagnostic myproject.vcxproj`.

(Detailed verbosity may also include the Property and Item listings; I'm not 100% sure; I always use Diagnostic verbosity when I need to do this.  I like to get as much data as I can get.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty ugly solution but if you just want to compare a before/after state of the macros maybe it will be good for you.

Select the project which you want to analyze. In the `Visual Studio` main menu go to the

> Tools => Visual Studio Command Prompt

If you don't have this menu item then [read this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/running-the-command-prompt-from-visual-studio-tools-menu/).

1. Run the command prompt.
2. From the command prompt call `set`.
3. Copy the results into a `.txt` file.

Do this before and after the `*.props` file modification and then compare the files.

Comment: +1 but, The variables defined in MSbuild scripts (*.target, *.props) wont available in VS command prompt.